# how to make a django subcategory

Tags: python, django, models

How do i make a subcategory for django.
I want something like this Question  -> year -> Mathematic

this is my model

```
    class Category(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name

    class PastQuestion(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
        subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        question = models.TextField()
        posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=50)

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.subject`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a foreign key to itself:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   ...
   parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, you can assign any existing Category instance as the parent_category of that instance. Furthermore, if you wanted to find all of the subcategories of a given Category instance you would do something like:

```
subcategories = Category.objects.filter(
    parent_category__id=target_category.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Category( models.Model ):
Title    = models.CharField( max_length=255, blank=True, null=False, ) 
parents = models.ForeignKey('self',limit_choices_to = {'parents__isnull': True}, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1, blank=True, null=True, )
```

try